# How to start new process in terminal without kill the one which still running

Tags: google-chrome, gnome-terminal

**ex.** when i open `google-chrome` through terminal i can't write command lines anymore, is there a way to start new command line in same terminal window without closing chrome ?

Comment: Follow the program name with `&`

Answer (score 0):

use the & to put the process in the background. e.g.:

```
open google-chrome &
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just open another terminal window and run your command